# Fitting starts when importing model in Pymc

Tags: python, numpy, pymc

UPDATE: Checking the stack trace, I could see that MCMC is being called. Why is that?

When importing my model I get the attached output. I am not sure what is pyMC is doing. It looks like an output of fitting, yet I didn't call any fitting procedure.

```
step: 1 potentials:[4.9537616968132445, 4.9537616968132445,4.9537616968132445, 5.6614419392151367, 5.6614419392151367, 5.6614419392151367, 5.6614419392151367, 5.6614419392151367, 5.6614419392151367, 5.6614419392151367] value_best:4.95376169681
step: 2 potentials:[4.2460814544113523, 4.2460814544113523, 4.9537616968132445, 4.9537616968132445, 4.2460814544113523, 4.9537616968132445, 4.9537616968132445, 5.9537616968132445, 5.6614419392151367, 5.6614419392151367, 4.9537616968132445, 4.9537616968132445] value_best:4.24608145441
step: 3 potentials:[3.5384012120094606, 4.2460814544113523,
```

I did not call Model or MCMC or MAP or anything, just imported my model.

Here is my model:

```
from pymc import DiscreteUniform,Uniform, stochastic,deterministic
from rushhour import min_manhattan_distance, opt_solution_instances
from astar import LRTA
import numpy as np
from test import instance_set
from csv import DictReader
from random import random

__all__=['instances','subject_error_rates','learning_iter',
'h_epsilon','model_error_rates']


@deterministic()
def subject_error_rates():
    return np.array([1.2 for i in instance_set[:20]])


learning_iter=DiscreteUniform('learning_iter', lower=1, upper=10, doc='learning_iter')

h_epsilon = Uniform('h_epsilon',lower=0.,upper=1.)

instances=np.array(instance_set[:20])

@deterministic
def model_error_rates(instances=instances,h_epsilon=h_epsilon,learning_iter=learning_iter):
    def f(x):
        return float(opt_solution_instances[i.name])/len(LRTA(i,heur=lambda x: h_epsilon*min_manhattan_distance(x),update_h=True,iters=learning_iter))
    return [f(i) for i in instances]
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong but not sure what it is, any hints?

Comment: You called `deterministic()` (twice), `DiscreteUniform(...)`, `Uniform(...)`, and `np.array(...)`.  Try adding some print statements to see which one is resulting in the output.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser My question is more general. Checking the stack trace, I could see that MCMC is being called. Why is that?

Comment: When you do an `import` in Python, the imported module is executed.  So all the code in `model.py` (assuming that's the name) is run when you do `import model` in some other file.

Comment: *"Checking the stack trace..."* What stack trace are you talking about?  It would probably be helpful to add that to the question.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I don't know if this is relevant to the question. I used 'trace' to find out what is being called when I import my model. 
Of course all code is imported. I nowhere in this file called MCMC(). So I'm not sure why this happens. Any idea?

Comment: Simple idea: start taking stuff out until the unexpected behavior stops occurring.